# Please suggest how to achieve the following o/p in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

[image: output]

input:

```
insert into example (fileno,type_cd,date_tm,be_nm) values('1','mismatch','match','mismatch');
insert into example (fileno,type_cd,date_tm,be_nm) values('2','match','mismatch','mismatch');
insert into example (fileno,type_cd,date_tm,be_nm) values('3','match','mismatch','match');
insert into example (fileno,type_cd,date_tm,be_nm) values('4','match','mismatch','mismatch');
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+pivot) for many answers

Comment: How to achieve the o/p in the picture through oracle?

Comment: Please formatted post text rather than images. I don't see how you get that output from the sample input though. Why does `type_cd` have 2 mismatches, for instance, when the data only shows 1? Or did you just miss a row off the input data?

Answer (score 3):

You could unpivot your initial data:

```
select *
from example
unpivot (match for column_name in
  (type_cd as 'type_cd', date_tm as 'date_tm', be_nm as 'be_nm'));

    FILENO COLUMN_ MATCH   
---------- ------- --------
         1 type_cd mismatch
         1 date_tm match   
         1 be_nm   mismatch
         2 type_cd match   
         2 date_tm mismatch
         2 be_nm   mismatch
...
```

and then pivot that:

```
select *
from (
  select column_name, match
  from example
  unpivot (match for column_name in
    (type_cd as 'type_cd', date_tm as 'date_tm', be_nm as 'be_nm'))
)
pivot (count(*) for (match) in ('match' as match, 'mismatch' as mismatch));

COLUMN_NAME      MATCH   MISMATCH
----------- ---------- ----------
type_cd              3          2
date_tm              1          4
be_nm                2          3
```

Or slightly less typing, but perhaps also less clear:

```
select *
from (select type_cd, date_tm, be_nm from example)
unpivot (match for column_name in
  (type_cd as 'type_cd', date_tm as 'date_tm', be_nm as 'be_nm'))
pivot (count(*) for (match) in ('match' as match, 'mismatch' as mismatch));

COLUMN_NAME      MATCH   MISMATCH
----------- ---------- ----------
type_cd              3          2
date_tm              1          4
be_nm                2          3
```

I've assumed you missed a row in the input, for 5/mismatch/mismatch/match, as without it you don't get those totals.

---

Or there is the brute-force approach, which involves conditional aggregation and unioning the results of several queries together, which requires hitting the table multiple times:

```
select 'type_cd' as column_name,
  count(case when type_cd = 'match' then 1 end) as match, 
  count(case when type_cd = 'mismatch' then 1 end) as mismatch
from example
union all
select 'date_tm' as column_name,
  count(case when date_tm = 'match' then 1 end) as match, 
  count(case when date_tm = 'mismatch' then 1 end) as mismatch
from example
union all
select 'be_nm' as column_name,
  count(case when be_nm = 'match' then 1 end) as match, 
  count(case when be_nm = 'mismatch' then 1 end) as mismatch
from example;

COLUMN_NAME      MATCH   MISMATCH
----------- ---------- ----------
type_cd              3          2
date_tm              1          4
be_nm                2          3
```

The unpivot/pivot approach probably scales better, for both performance and maintainability.